# Create tasks programmatically in Project Server 2013

Tags: 2013, tasks, csom, project-server

I'm trying to create a simple task in a Project, using Project Server 2013 CSOM. I have looked everywhere, but i couldn't find anything that would solve this issue.

I can create a new empty project just fine using CSOM, but i can't create tasks in it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you might try if you are still looking. This is powershell but will add tasks from a CSV file. You need the project Guid and task names. It created a parent task (Mine is hard coded but not necessary) then creates the sub tasks.
Here is the code:

cls

```
function Load_SPAddin()
{
$ver = $host | select version
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = “ReuseThread”}
if ((Get-PSSnapin “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell” -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
    {
    Add-PSSnapin “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell”
    }
}

Load_SPAddin

#Lets open the CSV (CSV is faser than Excel) 
$TaskList = Import-CSV "C:\test.csv"
$PriorProjGUID = ""

FOREACH ($Task in $TaskList) 
{

# Get the project GUID from the file. "ProjectGUID" is the header name of the column in the CSV File
# And we will grab the task name as well since we are here
$ProjGUID = $Task.ProjectGUID
$TaskName = $Task.TaskName 
# Lets do this while the project is the same
If ($ProjGUID -ne $PriorProjGUID) 
{
 #let's save, publish and checkin the project if there is a new one in the list 
  If ($PriorProjGUID -ne "")
    {
        # Add the above dataset to project and publish and check in 
        $ProjSvcProxy.QueueAddToProject($NewJobGuid, $SessionGUID, $ProjDataSet, $false); 
        $ProjSvcProxy.QueuePublish($NewJobGuid, $PriorProjGuid, "true","") 
     ## Start-sleep 20 
        $ProjSvcProxy.QueueCheckInProject($NewJobGuid, $PriorProjGuid, $false, $SessionGuid, $SessionDescr); 
     }  

  #Let's set the project name to the prior projct name so we can track our loop
   $PriorProjGUID = $ProjGUID  


  # we will open the project in this seciton first we have to set session variables and the like 
    # Set our variables 
    $SessionGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid() 
    $SessionDescr = "Add tasks session"  
    #$NewJobGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid() 
    $EPMTYGUID = [system.guid]::empty 
    $PWAUrl = “http://YOURSITE/pwa” 


    # initiate the PSI Web Services 
    #Project Web Service 
    $ProjSvcURL = $PWAUrl + "/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx?wsdl" 
    $ProjSvcProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $ProjSvcURL -useDefaultCredential #-credential $Credential 
    $QSvcUrl = $pwaUrl + "/_vti_bin/PSI/QueueSystem.asmx?wsdl" 
    $QSvcProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $QSvcUrl -useDefaultCredential #-credential $Credential 

    # Now let's check the project out 
     $ProjSvcProxy.CheckOutProject("$ProjGuid", $sessionGuid, $SessionDescr); 

    #give it a chance to check out 
    ##Start-sleep 30 

    # Add tasks.  
     $ProjDataset = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1_vti_bin_PSI_Project_asmx_wsdl.ProjectDataSet  

       #create a summary task
         $NewTaskGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid() 
         $NewTaskRow1 = $ProjDataSet.Task.NewTaskRow(); 
         $NewTaskRow1.PROJ_UID = $ProjGuid; 
         $NewTaskRow1.TASK_UID = $NewTaskGuid; 
         $NewTaskRow1.Task_IS_SUMMARY = 1;
         $NewTaskRow1.Task_OUTLINE_LEVEL = 1;
         $NewTaskRow1.TASK_DUR_FMT = 53;
         $NewTaskRow1.TASK_NAME = "EPR-ID: Asset Tasks";
         $NewTaskRow1.Task_DUR_IS_EST = 1;
       $ProjDataSet.Task.AddTaskRow($NewTaskRow1); 


  }



 $NewTaskGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid() 
 $NewTaskRow1 = $ProjDataSet.Task.NewTaskRow(); 
 $NewTaskRow1.PROJ_UID = $ProjGuid; 
 $NewTaskRow1.TASK_UID = $NewTaskGuid 
 $NewTaskRow1.TASK_DUR_FMT = 53; 
 $NewTaskRow1.TASK_DUR = 0;   
 $NewTaskRow1.TASK_NAME = $TaskName; 
 $NewTaskRow1.Task_OUTLINE_LEVEL = 2;
 $NewTaskRow1.TASK_START_DATE = '8/1/2015' #[datetime]::Now; 
 $ProjDataSet.Task.AddTaskRow($NewTaskRow1); 


}  

#Check in the last project
# Add the above dataset to project and publish and check in 
$ProjSvcProxy.QueueAddToProject($NewJobGuid, $SessionGUID, $ProjDataSet, $false); 
$ProjSvcProxy.QueuePublish($NewJobGuid, $ProjGuid, "true","") 
#  Start-sleep 5 
$ProjSvcProxy.QueueCheckInProject($NewJobGuid, $ProjGuid, $false, $SessionGuid, $SessionDescr); 
Echo "We are all Done but the Queue has to finish that will take some time"
```